# Как сократить код, когда у тебя много блоков которые работают через toggle. Функционал один и тот же, а методов 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я сделал функционал как надо, но у меня 4 функции независимые друг от друга, а функционал один и тот же. Реально оптимизировать код?

Через хуки тоже можно

Спасибо!

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import Conteiner from './Conteiner';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    showServices: 'hidden',
    showNews: 'hidden',
    showGallery: 'hidden',
    showUsefullInfo: 'hidden'
  };

  isToggleServices = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.dataset.show]:
        this.state.showServices === 'show' ? 'hidden' : 'show'
    });
  };
  isToggleNews = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.dataset.show]: this.state.show === 'show' ? 'hidden' : 'show'
    });
  };
  isToggleGallery = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.dataset.show]:
        this.state.showGallery === 'show' ? 'hidden' : 'show'
    });
  };
  isToggleUsefullInfo = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.dataset.show]:
        this.state.showGallery === 'show' ? 'hidden' : 'show'
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      isToggleNews,
      isToggleGallery,
      isToggleUsefullInfo,
      isToggleServices
    } = this;
    const { showNews, showGallery, showUsefullInfo, showServices } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Conteiner
          data={'showServices'}
          show={showServices}
          toggle={isToggleServices}
          block={`Block - 1`}
        />
        <Conteiner
          data={'showNews'}
          show={showNews}
          block={`Block - 2`}
          click={isToggleNews}
        />
        <Conteiner
          data={'showGallery'}
          show={showGallery}
          block={`Block - 3`}
          click={isToggleGallery}
        />
        <Conteiner
          data={'showUsefullInfo'}
          show={showUsefullInfo}
          block={`Block - 4`}
          click={isToggleUsefullInfo}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

### Conteiner.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const Conteiner = ({ show, block, toggle, data }) => {
  return (
    <div data-show={data} onClick={toggle} className={`${show} hidden-block`}>
      <span data-show={data} onClick={toggle} className={`close ${show}`}>
        Close
      </span>
      <h2 style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>{block}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Conteiner;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да забей в строку к чему нужно обратиться

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
    showServices: 'hidden',
    showNews: 'hidden',
    showGallery: 'hidden',
    showUsefullInfo: 'hidden'
};
show = (e, s) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.dataset.show]:this.state[s] === 'show' ? 'hidden' : 'show'
    });
};
isToggleServices = e => {this.show(e,'showServices');};
isToggleNews = e => {this.show(e,'showNews');};
isToggleGallery = e => {this.show(e,'showGallery');};
isToggleUsefullInfo = e => {this.show(e,'showUsefullInfo');};
```

Comment: Спасибо. А такой вариант в продакшн версии юзают?

Comment: Лично Вы, использовали бы такой вариант?

Comment: смотря какая цель, если нужно все уместить в один объект, то да, а если допускается изменение объекта после его объявления, то использовал бы цикл. Но на мой взгляд так более прозрачно все.

Answer (score 1):

Работоспособность не проверял и возможны ошибки, но я думаю идея понятна

```js
isToggle = e => {
  this.setState({ ...this.state,
    [e.target.dataset.show]: this.state.showServices === 'show' ? 'hidden' : 'show'
  });
};
```

```js
render() {
  const containers = Object.keys(this.state).map((key, index) => (
    <Container
       data={key}
       show={this.state[key]}
       click={isToggle}
       block={`Block - ${index}`}
       key={key}
    />
  );

  return (<>{containers}</>)
}
```